# Is negative 20 equal to negative 20? May be not!

Tags: puzzle

Proof:

Using simple Algebra it can be proved that -20 $\neq$ -20. Is it Algebraically correct, can I treat this as a puzzle only?

[image]

Comment: It is not algebraically correct.

Comment: Well, it is not algebraically correct =]. Look at T. Bongers' answer.

Comment: I need to edit my question, especially when i said it is algebraically correct.

Comment: People this is just a puzzle which I have put not to get downvote but rather suggestions. Id appreciate someone deleting the question rather than downvote. Please think logically!

Comment: $\displaystyle{\large\sqrt{\,x^{2}\,}\, = \left\vert\,x\,\right\vert}$

Comment: In other words, the problem stems from the fact that the function $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ mapping $x$ to $x^2$ is not injective. I could invent my own "proof" using the same idea. Since I am crazy I will assume $1=1$, of all things! Then, $\cos(0)=\cos(2\pi)$, and so $\cos^{-1}(\cos(0))=\cos^{-1}(\cos(2\pi))$, or $0=2\pi$. What could I have possibly done wrong?!

Answer (score 10):

The assertion that

$$\sqrt{\left(4 - \frac 9 2\right)^2} = \sqrt{\left(5 - \frac 9 2\right)^2} \implies 4 - \frac 9 2 = 5 - \frac 9 2$$
is false; in particular, this step assumes that

$$|x| = |y| \implies x = y$$
which is certainly false. Hence this is not algebraically correct.

Comment: Thats the begining step for proving that -20 $\neq$-20. Indirectly you hv answered my question.

Comment: Infact this where the proof comes from.